# не работает команда unban

Tags: python, discord.py

Вроде написал всё правильно, но не хочет разбанивать.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx,*, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send("Разбанено")

        return
```

Comment: Ошибку выдаёт какую-нибудь?

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка, нет